# Make xticklabels bold

Tags: matlab, plot, graphics, properties, label

I am trying to make xticklabels (cell array) bold. I tried some variations of this:

```
h=figure(1);
gca.XAxis.TickLabel='\bf{%g}'  % xticklabel is preassigned in box plot as text from cell array {'AB','CD','EF','GH'}.
```

However, most resulted in an error like

```
Error using set, 
Conversion to double from struct is not possible
```

Please suggest a fix for the above, and if possible, the default property setter for this effect.

I'm working with MATLAB 2017a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will make the `XTickLabels` bold:

```
fig = figure(1); 
ax = axes;           % or: ax = gca;
plot(rand(10));
ax.XTickLabel = cellfun(@(a) ['\bf{' a '}'], ax.XTickLabel, 'UniformOutput',false);
```

You cannot use `gca` in the same way as I used `ax`, since `gca` is a function that will return the current axes, and dot indexing a function is not possible.

If you want to use `set` (and `get`), you can do it as follows,

```
currentLabels = get(gca, 'XTickLabel');
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', cellfun(@(a) ['\bf{' a '}'], currentLabels, 'UniformOutput',false));
```

Comment: I see Dev-iL's anwer is cleaner than mine. I used this way in the past to set some specific labels bold, not all.

Comment: Don't undersell your solution, since if I'm not mistaken it provides more flexibility: by using such tex / latex tricks, one can make only a part of the label bold. Have a +1 on me :)

Answer (score 3):

You should change the `FontWeight` property of the `XAxis` object to `'bold'`, e.g.:

```matlab
figure();
set(get(gca, 'XAxis'), 'FontWeight', 'bold');
```

Result:

[image]